# Can I choose token id to mint from Candy Machine collection?

Tags: metaplex, metaplex-js, candy-machine-v2

I have Candy Machine V2 with 10 tokens with different 0.png - 9.png images.

I would like to mint those tokens in specific order, can I pass some id to mint function to achieve that?

For now I was using `await this.metaplex.candyMachinesV2().mint({ candyMachine });`
Can I add some parameter so that for example next mint would be token with metadata 5.png ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, minting with candy machine v2 is always randomized.

You could either mint those NFTs manually (with metaboss or http://sol-tools.tonyboyle.io/ ) or use sequential minting with cm v3.